# Simple form validation in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, validation, sencha-touch

I've seen several examples of form validation in Sencha Touch, but all seem overly complex for what I want to do. I don't need a model or store, as the fields in question will be handled server-side. Is there any easy way to simply check if the field in a form is populated before submitting it?

I've tried

```
if (myForm.getComponent('fieldset').getComponent('myField').length == 0)
{
    /// Do something
}
```

but the condition isn't met even when the field is empty. No JS errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the field's value first. You're probably always failing the condition, because `.length` is being evaluated against that component and not its text, so if the component is defined, its length will always be greater than zero.

Try this:

```
if (myForm.getComponent('fieldset').getComponent('myField').getValue().length == 0)
{
    /// Do something
}
```